Making the 'background-image' property act like the 'img' property
I must replace the image I embedded as an img link with background-image - to be able to use an effect only possible with background-image.
The problem is when I tried to have the same width as in the img element style - with the background-image property, it cropped the image, instead of letting it overflow beneath the right panel.
I don't have a clue how to fix that - maybe because I'm still relatively new to it.
Note that I also need the background-image to enable scrolling down - which is currently disabled.
Would be glad to get some help.
Thank you!
THIS IS DISPLAYING WITH THE img ELEMENT (NORMALLY):


/* The Flexbox */

.drag-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* Divider of panel-one & panel-two [Affects panel-two] */

[class^="panel"] {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Left Panel */

.panel-one {
  width: 48.6%;
}

/* Right Panel */

.panel-two {
  flex: 1;
  width: 52.4%;
}

/* The Vertical Line in The Middle of the Screen */

.dragbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: rgb(25, 0, 75);
}

/* The Circle inside the Middle of the Vertical Line */

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.reference-image {
  width: 119.1%;
  height: 100%;
}

.banner-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="img.css">

  <title>COPY</title>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="drag-container">
    <div class="panel-one" ; id="drag-left">
      <img class="reference-image"; src="https://i.sstatic.net/bfktZlUr.png">
    </div>

    <div class="dragbar" ; id="dragbar">
      <div class="slider" ; style="top: 50vh; position: sticky;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-two" ; id="drag-right">
      <div class="container">

        <img class="banner-image"; src="https://i.sstatic.net/cWsXnhwg.png">

        <div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </header>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



THIS IS DISPLAYING WITH THE background-image PROPERTY (CROPPED):


.d2 {
  width: 42%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.sstatic.net/bfktZlUr.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* The Flexbox */

.drag-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* Divider of panel-one & panel-two [Affects panel-two] */

[class^="panel"] {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Left Panel */

.panel-one {
  width: 48.6%;
}

/* Right Panel */

.panel-two {
  flex: 1;
  width: 52.4%;
}

/* The Vertical Line in The Middle of the Screen */

.dragbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: rgb(25, 0, 75);
}

/* The Circle inside the Middle of the Vertical Line */

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.reference-image {
  width: 119.1%;
  height: 100%;
}

.banner-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css">

  <title>COPY</title>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="drag-container">
    <div class="panel-one" ; id="drag-left">
       <div class="d2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="dragbar" ; id="dragbar">
      <div class="slider" ; style="top: 50vh; position: sticky;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-two" ; id="drag-right">
      <div class="container">

        <img class="banner-image"; src="https://i.sstatic.net/cWsXnhwg.png">

        <div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </header>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



THE ZOOM EFFECT (By Brett Donald, StackOverflow):


const d2 = document.querySelector('.d2')
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (!evt.target.dataset.index) return
  d2.className = "d2"
  switch(Number(evt.target.dataset.index)) {
    case 1:
      d2.classList.add('zoom','cyan')
      break
    case 2:
      d2.classList.add('zoom','yellow')
      break
    case 3:
      d2.classList.add('zoom','green')
      break
    case 4:
      d2.classList.add('zoom','blue')
      break
    case 5:
      d2.classList.add('zoom','red')
      break
    case 6:
      d2.classList.add('zoom','navy')
      break
  }
})
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.d1 {
    padding: 1em;
}

.d2 {
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://i.sstatic.net/bfktZlUr.png);
    background-size: 30%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.d2.zoom {
    background-size: 150%;
}

.d2.cyan {
    background-position: right 16%;
}

.d2.yellow {
    background-position: right 30%;
}

.d2.green {
    background-position: right 44%;
}

.d2.blue {
    background-position: right 58%;
}

.d2.red {
    background-position: right 72%;
}

.d2.navy {
    background-position: right 86%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="zoom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d1">
        <p>Zoom to different sections with the buttons below</p>
        <button data-index="0">Reset</button>
        <button data-index="1">Cyan</button>
        <button data-index="2">Yellow</button>
        <button data-index="3">Green</button>
        <button data-index="4">Blue</button>
        <button data-index="5">Red</button>
        <button data-index="6">Navy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="d2"></div>

      <script src="zoom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



Thanks!

perhaps your code will explain the issue better

Is your actual image same origin as the page? That would help

Ohh you mean the 'background-origin'? How do I make it the same origin of the page? Thank you!!

no, network origin

Oh yeah it's in the same folder

or, if you know it's size, use that in some way to calculate the size of .d2

I need the 'background-image' to display on the screen just as if I was using  - I don't know if changing the size would really change something

change the size of the .d2 and then play with background-size as well - seeing as the images in the code you posted are not the images you actually have, it's a bit hard to tell you exactly what you need to do

Yeah man that worked!! Thank you very much!!! But now I also need it to be scrollable - I remember at first I was actually using 'background-image' and was able to scroll, but I don't remember how do I get it back - do you know something about making background image scrollable? Thank you!!

What background-image effect do you want to use that isn’t possible with an img element? There may be a different way of achieving it,

Added the codes, here we go! Thanks! @AHaworth

I don't think there any background-image effect that you can't achieve with <img>. It's the other way around.

Why not just scale the img?

Is there a way to scale the image - without touching its 'width' and 'height'? Thank you! @AHaworth

I was thinking of using css scale as that doesn’t change the space taken up, it’s just visual.

Ohh I see, I'll try that, thank you very much!! (First time I hear about this property) =)) @AHaworth

scale has fairly recently become a css property in its own right so for older browser versions you may still have to use transform scale.

I see, it works very efficiently and simply but the problem is it displays the img above all the elements - but most importantly over the dragbar itself @AHaworth
